# My data doesn't save on my database - C# visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this problem, visual studio don't show any kind of error, but when i try to save the data and i go check my data base, it's empty, don't know where the error is, little help please

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace PAPA
{
    public partial class Form11 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\Documents\basededadospap.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        public Form11()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        void Fillcombo() {
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (textBox1.Text != "" & textBox2.Text != "" & textBox3.Text != "" & textBox4.Text != "" & textBox5.Text != "")
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\Documents\basededadospap.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO fornecedor (nomefornecedor,nmrcontribuinte,morada,email,obs) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "', '" + textBox4.Text + "' , '" + textBox5.Text + "')";
                    cmd.Clone();
                    MessageBox.Show(" Fornecedor inserido com sucesso! ");
                    cn.Close();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: is an exception being thrown?

Comment: when you go and check the database, are you looking at the LocalDB instance?

Comment: You're never *executing* the command, as far as I can see... Also, you should *absolutely* learn about SQL injection attacks and parameterized SQL, right now.

Comment: thanks everyone, i'm new sorry about that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Obviously, you *never* execute your command.

Use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute it. And your `Clone` seems unnecessary since you don't *keep* the copied command of that.

But much more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
string conString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\Documents\basededadospap.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
     cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO fornecedor (nomefornecedor,nmrcontribuinte,morada,email,obs) 
                         VALUES (@nome, @nmr, @mora, @email, @obs)";
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", textBox1.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nmr", textBox2.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mora", textBox3.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", textBox4.Text);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@obs", textBox5.Text);

     connection.Open();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I used `AddWithValue` method in my example since I didn't know your column types but you don't use this method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) sometimes. Use [`Add` overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify your parameter type and it's size.